# Sort an Excel table by values of a dynamic array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, list, sorting, dynamic

I'm trying to sort an Excel Table by values of an Array.

I have data in this format which I want to filter a table based on.

```
India 
USA
China
```

I have the country column in field 4, the table can be sorted in this way

```
Worksheets("Pilot").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter
Field:=4, _
Criteria1:=Array("India", "USA", "China"), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

However I want to sort the table by strings from an Array since I have 100+ values that I want to sort the table by.

I have tried to create an Array but I can't get the table filtered by the Array. The Array gets created but the table does just filter the first value of the Array. The Array becomes one dimensional I don't know if that is a problem? So if I want to get the 3rd value of my Array I have to call:

```
Myarray(3,1)
```

I have tried this

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant
StartRow = 13
LastRow = Cells(StartRow, "X").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
MyArray = Range(Cells(StartRow, "X"), Cells(LastRow, "X")).Value

Worksheets("Pilot").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
Field:=4, _
Criteria1:= MyArray, _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This does just filter the table by the first value of the Array.

So the expected result is to get text values from a column and then sort a table based on these values.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It's happening because you are creating a 2-D  array, and `Autofilter` takes an 1-D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

- When we assign values to an Array using `Range` object, the resulting Array is a 2-D array. But `Range.Autofilter` takes an 1-D array.

**Try This:**

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim arr() As Variant
StartRow = 13

LastRow = Cells(StartRow, "X").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
MyArray = Range(Cells(StartRow, "X"), Cells(LastRow, "X")).Value

ReDim arr(1 To UBound(MyArray))

For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        arr(i) = MyArray(i, 1)
Next

Worksheets("Pilot").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Thanks man for the heads-up with the 2-D Array I did not know that, the code solved my problem. Happy Friday, cheers!

Comment: Cheers Mate :) Glad to help